# Hide div with toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some troubles with my code, i want to hide div if one div is present to each product. I use .length for detect if div is present.

There are two div :

Div 1 : product to buy
Div 2 : Product sell

Today, they two div is show, i want to div hide the div 1 if div 2 is present in the product.

It's work for this case, but if the product is just check to "to buy", the div is hide..

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.item-wrap').each(function () {
      if($('span.label-status-82').length){  // return's true if element is present
         // show or hide another div
         $("span.label-status.label-status-69.label.label-default").hide();
      }
      else {
         $("span.label-status.label-status-69.label.label-default").show(); 
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="figure-block">
  <figure class="item-thumb">


    <div class="label-wrap label-right">
      <span class="label-status label-status-69 label label-default"><a href="">ACHETER</a></span><span class="label-status label-status-82 label label-default"><a href="#">VENDU</a></span> </div>
    </a>
    <div class="item-price-block hide-on-list">
      <span class="item-price item-price-text"></span> </div>

  </figure>
</div>
```

I tried with this code

```
$('.label-wrap.label-right').each(function(index, domEle){ 
    if($("span.label-status").hasClass("label-status-82")) { 
         console.log('test'); 
         $("span.label-status.label-status-69.label.label-default").hide();
    } 
    else if ($(".label-wrap.label-right span.label-status").hasClass("label-status-69")) { 
         console.log('test2'); $("span.label-status.label-status-69.label.label-default").show();
    } 
});
```

It's work just for the if, the each stop after :'(. Thx

Comment: you can use function `.hasClass('<class_name>')` for checking of the presence of the given class.

Comment: @LouisBepalme please post corresponding html sample code when asking for help with javascript/jquery.

Comment: I update my message with HTML ! Thank you so much

Comment: You are using an "if" followed by an "else if".  If the code outputs "test", it will never get to "test2".

Comment: How can I get him to take the test2?

Comment: Your code has a start </a> tag.  Please correct as non valid HTML causes all sorts of issues.